# Get the configurable child products

Tags: php, magento, parent-child

Here comes a new challenge! I already tried everything to get the child products of a configurable product, but nothing works. The thing is, I need to get the stock quantity of a simple product which is inside a configurable product, which is inside a grouped product, so, first of all I loaded the grouped product and got it's product id according to the code.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
$productId = $product->getId();
```

then i got the configurable product which is inside the product I just loaded.

```
$groupedAssociatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
```

this code is returning an array for me, with all details of the configurable product, and I can't get the products that are associated to this product and so it's stock quantity. Does anyone can give me a help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is the answer to my own question.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
$productId = $product->getId();

$groupedAssociatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
foreach ($groupedAssociatedProducts as $value) {
    $idConfigurableProduct = $value->getId();
}    

$configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idConfigurableProduct);
$configurableAssociatedProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $configurableProduct);
foreach ($configurableAssociatedProduct as $child) {
    $finalSimpleProduct = $child->getId();
}

$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($finalSimpleProduct)->getQty();
```